# Hypergraph coloring in linear hypergraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-colorings, hypergraph

Let $H=(V,E)$ be a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) with $V\neq\varnothing$ and $E \neq \varnothing$ such that

1. for all $e\in E$ we have $|e|\geq 2$, and
2. for all $e\neq e_1 \in E$ we have $|e\cap e_1|\leq 1$.

Is there a function $f: V\to E$ such that for all $e\in E$ the restriction $f{\restriction}_e$ is non-constant?

**EDIT.** By @bof's remark below, the case that $E$ is infinite, is trivial. Indeed I only wanted to ask the question for finite $V$ (and therefore finite $E$). Apologies for the omission.

Comment: If $E$ is infinite we can find a set $W\subseteq V$ such that $|W\cap e|\ge2$ for all $e\in E$, and $|W|\le|E|$, so we can take a function $f:V\to E$ whose restriction to $W$ is injective. I guess the finite case is equally trivial. It probably reduces to the case of ordinary finite graphs, and in that case it's clear that the chromatic number is less than or equal to the number of edges. By the way, do these questions have some kind of motivation? It might make the questions more interesting if we knew what the motivation was.

Comment: Right @bof I should have written it is for finite $V$ only - will edit the question. I was just playing around with linear hypergraphs, they also arise in formulations of statements equivalent to the Erdös-Faber-Lovasz conjecture. I also thought it would be trivial in the finite case, but I couldn't do it (which doesn't mean it isn't trivial).

Comment: If we replace each edge with a $2$-element subset, the number of edges does not increase and the chromatic number does not decrease, so no generality is lost by assuming the hypergraph is a ordinary finite graph. Now $\chi(G)\le\Delta(G)+1\le|E|$ unless the graph is a star, and then $\chi(G)\le2$, oops, looks like $K_2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I think the comment by @bof essentially covers the finite case too, except for the case of 2 vertices and one edge, in which case the result is false. In any other finite case, reduce to an ordinary graph (shrink each edge to have size 2) and assume it's connected (treat each component separately. Fix a spanning tree T and a vertex v. Let f map each vertex w$\neq$v to the edge of T leading from w toward v. That's injective, but we still need to map v somewhere. So we're OK unless T is the whole  graph and all its edges are incident to v. In that case, try again, starting with a different v.

Comment: In my comment, "the comment by @bof" refers to the first such comment; the second arrived while I was typing, and it completes the answer.